# Instrumentation of application to monitor changes of one register, ideas?

Tags: c, debugging, cpu-registers, instrumentation

I want to monitor a register change of an user-mode application and performance is an important matter for me. 
I want to know what are your ideas on how to monitor only one register changes to reach maximum performance. The idea must be platform independent.

Assume that in Intel Architecture I want to monitor ESP changes in the application being monitored.

One particular idea I thought about was to create a custom debugger and run the application within the debugger. However I am worried about performance issues. Does this mean that I have to modify the ptrace implementation to get better performance?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your fplatform? I mean: are you talking about low level embedded application or high level, such as Linux O.S:?

Comment: I am talking about high level user mode application. So Since you have background in Embedded, lets say I want to monitor LR changes in an application running in ARM. How I can do it light?

Comment: AFAIK, you have better chances of putting a watchpoint on a memory location than a register. I don't think there's a fast way to monitor all changes to the stack-pointer.

Comment: @EOF Thats the point of this question, I want to only monitor the register. monitoring the memory is not very platform independent. As I gave answer to LPs if I want to monitor LR register, there is no memory location to hold the values of LR as it is in ESP.

Comment: What I usually do is to define a global array and a global index, use them in order to cyclically-record the value of the register over a period of time, and then pause the program and observe the array through the debugger. For example: Declare `uint8_t globalArr[256] = {0}, globalInd = 0;`. Then, somewhere in your program, do `globalArr[globalInd++] = reg;`. Of course, if you want to record more than 256 entries (and less than 65536 entries), then you can't rely on the "wrap-around" trick, and you will have to set `globalInd` to 0 whenever it reaches the number of entries in `globalArr`.

Comment: The watch-point option mentioned above might also work for you, but beware that on some architectures it yields a considerable overhead during execution, which might lead to different behavior of your program, and possibly conceal whatever it is that you're trying to investigate (I just happen to be working on such an architecture at the moment).

Comment: @barakmanos your idea to add additional code to my program to monitor its registers is actually interesting. Regarding the watch-point  (if you refer to implementation of watch-point in GDB) I think it works in both ARM and Intel architecture. Can you elaborate more regarding in which architecture it causes considerable overhead? Do you mean ARM?

Comment: @barakmanos or you mean using CPU debug registers? Can those be used for monitoring registers?. Personally (I might be wrong) I think anything which is based on interrupt might be slow. then I end up to have no solution to register monitoring...

Comment: Using watchpoint or tracepoints will slow down your app. Maybe advanced debugging tools, like [Lauterbach](http://www.lauterbach.com/frames.html?home.html), could help you to trace registers. In any case I think that trace each single LR change is quite impossible, in particular if you are talking about very fast CPU.

Comment: MC1323x, which is a Freescale MCU with an HCS08 core. Not ARM neither Intel if that's what you're concerned with. If you just want to catch the moment in time where the register changes (or changes to a specific value), then a watch-point might be the best option for you. If you're interested in the "behavior" of the register over time, then I would recommend recording it into a global array (global, because it allows you to watch it in the debugger from any scope, and also because it prevents compiler optimization which might remove it altogether).

Comment: @SamaAzari: To the best of my knowledge, HW implementation for watch-points uses CPU registers **by definition** (how else would you do it?). I think that the technical terminology for this is a *Trap*.

Comment: If you are using gdb take a look at [THIS](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_10.html)

Comment: @barakmanos I think the only option now I see is the global arrays. However I am still looking for alternative ways.

Comment: @LPs Thats super interesting, I did not know gdb have such thing. will check its performance :P

Comment: I think it might help you to get a proper answer if you post more specific details, such as your code, the exact platform that you're using, the register that you're trying to trace and the general purpose of your investigation.